# Java EE authentication/authorization for automated task

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, jaas

I am making a Java EE application which needs to invoke some ejb methods based on some events.Since these ejb methods can be invoke only by  an admin, somehow the event listener need to be logged in as admin. Hard coding  admin username/password is not an option. I think this is a common scenario . Any idea/insights about how to tackle this?.

Generally  how such automated (without  a user ) tasks perform authentication/authorization?

Thanks in advance
Thakku

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several frameworks you can use in order to perform this task -
Maybe use Spring Security, or Apache Shiro, or even [PicketBox](http://www.jboss.org/picketbox) , But I would like to ask if this is really needed? 
Maybe you should use [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/index.html) in order to implement a login mechanism, and implement your own JAAS module that works some source holding username + password (you provide the credentials by implementing a Callback Handler). 
 I know JBoss implemented a JAAS module based on properties file. 
Start looking at these ideas, I think they will help you in your work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Mine is a very security sensitive application. So "who does what" is always recorded and there is a strict acl. I am using glassfish. But I think this problem is not specific to any framework or platform. i.e How a secured ejb method is  accessed by a thread without an actual user logged in ?, do i need to create a dummy user for the thread so that every thread will loggin using that dummy user credential ?.What is the common approach for this scenario (I think almost all security aware applications have this problem to tackle)